# IP whitelisting across Service and Marketing Clouds

Tags: marketing-cloud, ip-whitelisting

If I whitelist my IP addresses to access Service Cloud instance for my business do I need to re-do the same for Marketing Cloud? I assume so as Marketing Cloud is hosted elsewhere to service cloud but want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Correct - you need to whitelist two different sets of IP addresses for Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud. You can find the relevant IP addresses here:

[Core (Sales Cloud, Service Cloud, Community Cloud)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1)

[Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion_on_whitelists.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)